# How to set HTML list as mx:DataGrid data provider?

Tags: html, apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, datagrid

So I have Html like this http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/RecentChanges (I want to create some Flash Track reader which will be opensource)

I need to list in my DataGrid Index of all viki pages in form like

```
     +-----------+--------+
     |page name  |page url|   
     +-----------+--------+
     | name      | url    |
     +-----------+--------+
```

Comment: Do you want to know how to populate the DataGrid with a dataProvider? Or are you asking about how you could go about parsing the links out of the HTML source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you'd need some API to call instead of getting html page itself. Eclipse trac plugins are using http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/XmlRpcPlugin. Here's simple example how you'd do it on flex side:

http://jonniespratley.com/2008/10/02/adobe-flex-using-xml-rpc/

http://code.google.com/p/as3-rpclib/wiki/Resources

Cheers